# Finding or making a league table of popular questions

Tags: support

I've been clicking various links and interrogating Help. So far no luck.

I'd like to find or make a league table of the most popular questions of all time on the main Worldbuilding SE. I'm interested in upvotes and/or views .

Does such exist? If not, how can I build one?

Comment: For the most votes https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes

Comment: what's a league table?

Comment: I used it loosely without thinking, to refer to questions rather than teams - *League table noun
Definition of league table 
British
: a list of teams, schools, hospitals, etc. that shows them in order from best to worst*  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/league%20table

Answer (score 4):

For questions by votes, you can [search for `is:q` and sort by votes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq).

For answers by votes, you can [search for `is:a` and sort by votes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa).

To get a list of questions by views, you can use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. [Here's an example query](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/938848?opt.textResults=true) to get you started:

```
SELECT TOP(10)
  Id,
  ViewCount,
  Title,
  'https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Id) AS Link
FROM Posts
ORDER BY ViewCount DESC
```

(SEDE isn't using the most recent data -- I think it updates weekly -- but allows you to perform queries that are difficult or impossible to express in the on-site search field syntax.)

Comment: `views:#` is also a sort parameter on the site; you don't have to wait for the SEDE update.

Comment: @MonicaCellio `views:#` is a search criteria, but then you need to pick a threshold. (You can search for, e.g., `is:q views:50000..` which on Worldbuilding gives you a handful of questions.) I didn't see any way to *sort* by views. If I missed something, could you elaborate? [The help center page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/searching) doesn't even mention the words "sort" or "order".

Comment: Oh, sorting -- no, I don't know of a way to do that, unfortunately.

Comment: SEDE is fed by the weekly data dump that happens during the Sunday-->Monday overnight, GMT.

Answer (score 2):

## A timely question

[Datapalooza](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5691/holiday-data-palooza-site-statistics-from-2017) is just around the corner! I'm planning a more complete experience this year. Last year's focus was users, but this year's focus is going to be questions.

Basically, if you don't want to do it yourself as MichaelKjorling suggests, comment with what you want, and I will see if I can work that into Datapalooza this year. Now is the time to let me know!